# How can I create a border and curved corners on a map Fragment in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I want my map to have a border that goes around the edges and if possible to curve the corners just a little. I have no idea how to do this and there doesn't seem to be to when i google search. I'd appreciate any help at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom xml to meet your needs.

Create a new xml called curved_border in drawable/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
                android:radius="3dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#EFEFEF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
                    android:radius="3dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note: This will create a border of color #EFEFEF and the background of the rest of the fragment will be #FFFFFF. It will also add rounded corners of 3dp to your entire fragment. Set this xml as background of your fragment to see the effect.

You can change the colors accordingly to meet your needs. In the corners tag, I have included all separate options to define top and bottom radius if in case you need to customize it but if not required, then only android:radius attribute will be sufficient to add rounded corners.